# Prime power triples answer not correct

Tags: python, algorithm

I have tried [this](https://projecteuler.net/problem=87) problem but not able to get the right answer. Can anyone help me with spotting the problem in my code?

My logic: using seive, created the list of prime numbers. Using this prime number list i just brute forced the solution.

```
import math
n = 50000000
exponent = (2, 3, 4)
prime_numbers = [True]*n
prime_numbers[0] = False
prime_numbers[1] =  False
max_prime = 2

#prime number creation
for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n))+1):
        if prime_numbers[i]:
            for j in range(i*i, n, i):
                prime_numbers[j] = False

# list of prime numbers
list_data = []
for i in range(2, n):
    if prime_numbers[i]:
        if i**2 >= n:
            break
        list_data.append(i)

count = 0
for i, i_data in enumerate(list_data):
    if i_data**4 >= n:
        break
    for j, j_data in enumerate(list_data):
        if j_data**3 >= n:
            break
        for k, k_data in enumerate(list_data):
            if k_data**2 >= n:
                break
            if (k_data**2 + j_data**3 + i_data**4) < n:
                count += 1  
print(count)
```

Comment: Problem asks equal you write `if (k_data**2 + j_data**3 + i_data**4) < n:` that is minor

Comment: What if two choices of primes produce the same sum?

Comment: You can break the `for j` loop if `i_data ** 4 + j_data ** 3 >= n`, can you not?  That should save you some iterations, if nothing else.

Comment: I wonder why people down vote and that too without giving any reasons. Acting more like thugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never got output from your code.  I didn't wait for the sieve to finish.

A few tips:

1. The sieve is very slow.  Consider that the largest prime you need is the square root of 50,000,000 and you can speed it up considerably.
2. There is no need use `enumerate`.  `i`, `j` , `k` are never used.
3. You are counting duplicates.  Use a `set` to store unique values found.

I got the right answer in a few seconds taking the above into account so the algorithm works otherwise.

Comment: just added the square root and added the set for uniques and found the answer.